# Get foreach for meta_query value

Tags: meta-query, php

How can i get meta_box foreach value inside meta_query value, here is code:

```
$my_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "artist_name", true);
$artistNames = array();  
foreach($my_id as $id) {
    $artistNames[] = $id;
}
$artists = implode($artistNames,", ");

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array ( 'songs', 'videos' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'artist_name',
            'value' => array( $artists )
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

do this possible ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't implode `$artistNames`. The `value` `meta_query` argument will take an array if you use any of several `compare` arguments. You need `IN`, I believe.

> value (string|array) - Custom field value. It can be an array only
>   when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'....
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Assuming that `$artistNames` is an array of `id`s you can use it directly.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array ( 'songs', 'videos' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'artist_name',
            'value' => $artistNames,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

And in fact, it looks like you can skip that first `foreach` that generates `$artistNames` and just use `$my_id`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array ( 'songs', 'videos' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'artist_name',
            'value' => $my_id,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: $my_id is checkbox with multiple value, how can i get multiple value from "get_meta_box" for "meta_query value" ?

Comment: `get_meta_value()`, as in your question, but the third parameter is a `singular` argument. If you've saved an array (as your code implies) what I posted above should work. If you have saved individual key/value pairs you need the third parameter to be `false`, not `true`. Is that the question?